# Schematic representation of emitters

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]
I started drawing emitters, but I ran into difficulties.

```
    \documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % arc
        \draw
        (-0.15,0.3) % Coordinates of the arc center (x, y)
        arc (30:150:1); % Starting angle: 30 degrees, Ending angle: 150 degrees, Radius: 1
        
        
          % Vertical line
        \draw
        (-1,2) % Initial coordinates (x, y)
        -- % Operator for drawing a line
        (-1,0.1); % Final coordinates (x, y)
        
         % Horizontal line
        \draw
        (-1.4,0.1) % Initial coordinates  (x, y)
        -- % Оператор для рисования линии
        (-0.6,0.1); % Final coordinates (x, y)
        
        
        % Axes
        \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

it is required to draw a complete picture, but so far I have just started the emitter and do not know how to set the coordinates correctly and how to make it more similar.
[image]

A few hours later, I received such a drawing. Of course, it looks too little like the original:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        mylabel/.style={font=\scriptsize}
    }
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        antenna/.pic={
            % Antenna drawing
            \draw (-0.57,.15) arc(50:130:0.7);
            \draw (-1,1) -- (-1,.1);
            \draw (-1.2,.1) -- (-0.8,.1);
        },
        Pattern/.pic={
            % Radiation pattern drawing
            \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (0.1 and 0.5);
            \draw[dashed] (0,\R) -- (0,0);
        }
        ]
        
        % Positions of emitters and axis labels
        \def\positionOne{-1}
        \def\positionZero{0}
        \def\positionTwo{1}
        \def\R{2} % R
        \def\alpha{18} % Angle
        
        % Placement of emitters and radiation pattern
        \pic at (\positionOne+1,0.3) {antenna};
        \node[below, mylabel] at (\positionOne+0.5,1.2) {№ 1};
        \pic at (\positionTwo+1,0.3) {antenna};
        \node[below, mylabel] at (\positionTwo+0.5,1.2) {№ 2};
        \pic[rotate=-\alpha,scale=1, red!100] at (\positionZero,-\R) {Pattern};
        
        \draw[dashed] (\positionZero,-\R) -- (\positionZero,0);
        \node[below, mylabel] at (\positionZero-0.25,-\R/3) {R};
        
        \draw[dashed] (\positionZero,-\R) -- (\positionTwo,0);
        
        % Axes
        \draw[->] (\positionOne-0.5,0) -- (\positionTwo+0.5,0) node[right] {$X$};
        
        % Labels on the axis
        \node[below, mylabel] at (\positionOne,0) {$\positionOne$};
        \node[below, mylabel] at (\positionZero,0) {$\positionZero$};
        \node[below, mylabel] at (\positionTwo,0) {$\positionTwo$};
        
        % Ticks on the axis
        \foreach \x in {\positionOne,\positionZero,\positionTwo}
        \draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this part of an exercise or so?

Comment: in my work, I need to get a complete drawing of this installation

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like you need a library of common things. Again, to start, consider creating a handful of `\pic` elements. In the drawng shown these would be at least "antenna" and "coil".

Comment: Tell me, maybe it would be correct to save parts of my drawing (antennas, radiation pattern) created in inkscape separately in pdf, and then arrange them according to coordinates using latech?

I'm starting to realize that it's very difficult to draw, for example, a similar directional pattern here

Comment: Have a look at the graphicx package, which can render pdf files as well. Search via https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%7B%5Cincludegraphics for more details wrt Tikz.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, did the code compile in your environment? It does in mine, once I:

- turn `\Draw` into `\draw`
- turn two `.` into `,` with the coordinates
- start using the right position statements with nodes
- see the `% <<<` markings

It's also hard to tell, what you achieved, hence where you struggle, see screenshot below.

**Suggestions**:

- reviewing the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/) frequently is a good idea, including myself
- review `\node`
- look for polar coordinates
- consider using `\pic` for the antennas
- later: have a look into the angle library in said manual
- use `\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}` for development, at least

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Arc
        \draw   % <<<
(-(-0,15,0,3) % Arc modifier (x,y)
arc (30:150:1); % Starting angle: 0 degrees, Ending angle: 45 degrees, Radius: 1


% Vertical line
        \draw
        (-1,2) % Initial values (x, y) % <<<
-- % Line drawing operator
(-1,0.1); % Final values (x, y) % <<<

% Horizontal line
        \draw
        (-1.4,0.1) % Initial values (x, y)
-- % Line drawing operator
(-0,6,0,1); % Final values (x, y)


% of the Axis
        \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[right] {$x$}; % <<<
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$y$}; % <<<
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to draw one emitter in its coordinates, and then position it already on a common coordinate system, create a copy of it?

Comment: Yes, that's called ... `\pic`, see the manual. I'm adjusting your changed code for that. Will take a minute or "two".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adjusted example of how you could do it, assuming, you don't use it for military development (!) .

Had to retype portions of your text, which might be due to the different character systems used.

Some hints:

- when rotating the antenna, you see, its fixed point is not where you expect it: shift coordinates of your antennas details
- have a look at `+` and `++` syntax in the manual, which will simplify drawings like these
- axis are simple enough to create; turning them into `\pic` may be overdone

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        antenna/.pic={
            \draw (-.15,.3) arc(30:150:1);
            \draw (-1,2) -- (-1,.1);
            \draw (-1.4,.1) -- (-.6,.1);
        }
    ]

        
    % ~~~ placing some antennas ~~~~~~~~~~
    \pic at (0,2) {antenna};
    \pic[red!40] at (3,2) {antenna};
    \pic[rotate=30,scale=.5,thick,dashed] at (5,2) {antenna};
        
        
        % Axes
        \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I change the code further, should I change it in my response?

Comment: Fine. If it's still the same question, yes, best with a hint. If it's a new aspect, consider posting a new question. Unlike in a forum, here: 1 question == 1 problem, each answer == 1 solution. So if the problem changes, it should become a new question. If it's related, you can still add a link to it.